# Using existing code to update 2 separate worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

So I created a productivity tracker for our sales team based on the amount of calls they make per hour based on a simple push button. The code I'm using determines what day it is, what hour of the day it is and then increments by one each time the button is pushed. It takes into account our lunch hours as well and when the day ends and begins. However the issue I'm facing is right now it requires them to always be on that particular sheet for them to see it. I updated the code so that they could push the button from another sheet but I'd like to be able for them to see the total incremented number based on the day. Here is the existing code I'm using.

```
Sub OneclickUpdate()
    strTime = Hour(Now()) 'grabs the current hour on a 24 hour rotation
    Dim LWeekday As Integer

    LWeekday = Weekday(Date, vbMonday) 'Set Monday as day 1


    'Monday

    If strTime = 9 And LWeekday = 1 Then
        Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("C3").Value = Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("C3") + 1
    ElseIf strTime = 10 And LWeekday = 1 Then
        Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("C4").Value = Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("C4") + 1

    ElseIf strTime = 11 And LWeekday = 1 Then
        Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("C5").Value = Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("C5") + 1

    ElseIf strTime = 12 And LWeekday = 1 Then
        Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("C6").Value = Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("C6") + 1

    ElseIf strTime = 13 And LWeekday = 1 Then
        Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("C7").Value = Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("C7") + 1

    ElseIf strTime = 14 And LWeekday = 1 Then
        Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("C7").Value = Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("C7") + 1

    ElseIf strTime = 15 And LWeekday = 1 Then
        Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("C9").Value = Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("C9") + 1

    ElseIf strTime = 16 And LWeekday = 1 Then
        Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("C10").Value = Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("C10") + 1

    ElseIf strTime = 17 And LWeekday = 1 Then
        Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("C11").Value = Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("C11") + 1


    'Tuesday

    ElseIf strTime = 9 And LWeekday = 2 Then
         Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("E3").Value = Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("E3") + 1

    ElseIf strTime = 10 And LWeekday = 2 Then
        Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("E4").Value = Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("E4") + 1

    ElseIf strTime = 11 And LWeekday = 2 Then
        Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("E5").Value = Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("E5") + 1

    ElseIf strTime = 12 And LWeekday = 2 Then
        Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("E6").Value = Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("E6") + 1

    ElseIf strTime = 13 And LWeekday = 2 Then
        Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("E7").Value = Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("E7") + 1

    ElseIf strTime = 14 And LWeekday = 2 Then
        Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("E7").Value = Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("E7") + 1

    ElseIf strTime = 15 And LWeekday = 2 Then
        Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("E9").Value = Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("E9") + 1

    ElseIf strTime = 16 And LWeekday = 2 Then
        Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("E10").Value = Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("E10") + 1

    ElseIf strTime = 17 And LWeekday = 2 Then
        Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("E11").Value = Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("E11") + 1

    'Wednesday

    ElseIf strTime = 9 And LWeekday = 3 Then
         Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("G3").Value = Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("G3") + 1

    ElseIf strTime = 10 And LWeekday = 3 Then
        Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("G4").Value = Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("G4") + 1

    ElseIf strTime = 11 And LWeekday = 3 Then
        Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("G5").Value = Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("G5") + 1

    ElseIf strTime = 12 And LWeekday = 3 Then
        Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("G6").Value = Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("G6") + 1

    ElseIf strTime = 13 And LWeekday = 3 Then
        Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("G7").Value = Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("G7") + 1

    ElseIf strTime = 14 And LWeekday = 3 Then
        Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("G7").Value = Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("G7") + 1

    ElseIf strTime = 15 And LWeekday = 3 Then
        Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("G9").Value = Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("G9") + 1

    ElseIf strTime = 16 And LWeekday = 3 Then
        Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("G10").Value = Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("G10") + 1

    ElseIf strTime = 17 And LWeekday = 3 Then
        Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("G11").Value = Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("G11") + 1


    'Thursday

    ElseIf strTime = 9 And LWeekday = 4 Then
         Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("I3").Value = Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("I3") + 1

    ElseIf strTime = 10 And LWeekday = 4 Then
        Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("I4").Value = Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("I4") + 1

    ElseIf strTime = 11 And LWeekday = 4 Then
        Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("I5").Value = Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("I5") + 1

    ElseIf strTime = 12 And LWeekday = 4 Then
        Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("I6").Value = Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("I6") + 1

    ElseIf strTime = 13 And LWeekday = 4 Then
        Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("I7").Value = Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("I7") + 1

    ElseIf strTime = 14 And LWeekday = 4 Then
        Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("I7").Value = Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("I7") + 1

    ElseIf strTime = 15 And LWeekday = 4 Then
        Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("I9").Value = Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("I9") + 1

    ElseIf strTime = 16 And LWeekday = 4 Then
        Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("I10").Value = Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("I10") + 1

    ElseIf strTime = 17 And LWeekday = 4 Then
        Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("I11").Value = Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("I11") + 1



    'Friday

    ElseIf strTime = 8 And LWeekday = 5 Then
         Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("K2").Value = Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("K2") + 1

    ElseIf strTime = 9 And LWeekday = 5 Then
        Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("K3").Value = Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("K3") + 1

    ElseIf strTime = 10 And LWeekday = 5 Then
        Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("K4").Value = Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("K4") + 1

    ElseIf strTime = 11 And LWeekday = 5 Then
        Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("K5").Value = Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("K5") + 1

    ElseIf strTime = 12 And LWeekday = 5 Then
        Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("K6").Value = Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("K6") + 1

    ElseIf strTime = 13 And LWeekday = 5 Then
        Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("K6").Value = Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("K6") + 1

    ElseIf strTime = 14 And LWeekday = 5 Then
        Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("K8").Value = Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("K8") + 1

    ElseIf strTime = 15 And LWeekday = 5 Then
        Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("K9").Value = Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("K9") + 1

    ElseIf strTime = 16 And LWeekday = 5 Then
        Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range("K10").Value = Worksheets("Productivity 
        Tracker").Range("K10") + 1

    ElseIf strTime <> [8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17] Or LWeekday <> [1,2,3,4,5] Then
        MsgBox "Seriously, Enough work already, go home!"

    End If
End Sub
```

So say this productivity sheet is sheet B. I want to be able to put in cell A1 of sheet A the day and in cell B1 of sheet A the number  it has so far incremented. I hope that makes sense. Thank you so much for any assistance.

Comment: I'm trying to re write this for you, question: Every day at 1 PM and 2 PM they are added on the same Cell, is that intended? (12 and 1 on Friday)

Comment: Yes that is intended. That is when we take lunch at 1 and so sometimes we work into our lunch and we distribute those into the previous hour so they still get included..

Comment: Actually M-Th we take lunch at 2 and on Fridays its at 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you only want to know the total number on a different sheet, I named the sheet "SHEET A" and i took a different approach to make your code shorter.

Try this:

```
Sub OneclickUpdate()
    strTime = Hour(Now()) 'grabs the current hour on a 24 hour rotation
    Dim LWeekday As Integer, count As Integer
    Dim cols As Variant
    usedCol = Array("C", "E", "G", "I", "K")
    weekdayRow = Array(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 9, 10, 11)
    weekendRow = Array(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 8, 9, 10)
    LWeekday = Weekday(Date, vbMonday) 'Set Monday as day 1

    If strTime >= 8 And strTime <= 17 And LWeekday >= 1 And LWeekday <= 5 Then
        'The next two lines paste the date on A1 in Sheet A and Sheet B
        Worksheets("SHEET A").Range("A1").Value = Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yyyy")
        Worksheets("SHEET B").Range("A1").Value = Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yyyy")
        If LWeekday = 5 And strTime <> 17 Then
            With Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range(usedCol(LWeekday - 1) & weekendRow(strTime - 8))
                .Value = .Value + 1
                'The next two lines paste the Total number for the day on
                'Sheet A and Sheet B
                Worksheets("SHEET A").Range("B1").Value = .Value
                Worksheets("SHEET B").Range("B1").Value = .Value
            End With
        ElseIf LWeekday <> 5 And strTime <> 8 Then
            With Worksheets("Productivity Tracker").Range(usedCol(LWeekday - 1) & weekdayRow(strTime - 9))
                .Value = .Value + 1
                'The next two lines paste the Total number for the day on
                'Sheet A and Sheet B
                Worksheets("SHEET A").Range("B1").Value = .Value
                Worksheets("SHEET B").Range("B1").Value = .Value
            End With
        Else
            MsgBox "Seriously, Enough work already, go home!"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Seriously, Enough work already, go home!"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: First off thank you very much for the much appreciate shortening. You are correct in that I want to see it on another sheet but I want it on both Sheet A and B.

Comment: So you want also on SHEET B to have A1 with the Date and B2 with the totals? The same way this does with SHEET A?

Comment: Yes. Sorry im trying to answer here and work at the same time. Forgive me. So one sheet is where they track their production for calls. However they also have another sheet where they enter sales information. Often times they will be on the sales page for large sections of time. However during that time they might have made 5-6 calls. I want them to be able to have a button on the sales sheet that increments the totals in Production Tracker sheet but shows them on both pages what the current total is on both sheets.

Comment: I just edited the answer. Look at the lines after the comments, you can change that or add another line the same way and put the data on as many sheets as you want to show the total numbers. Try it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172276/discussion-between-gehn47-and-ricardo-a).